# If condition failed for unknown reasons

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following Python3 code:

```
parts = ['g109343.t1', '3e908dc966fefe367e64dc9d98b0d3ab', '1358', 'SMART', 'SM00343', '', '600', '616', '0.36', 'T', '17-07-2019', 'IPR001878', 'Zinc finger, CCHC-type', 'GO:0003676|GO:0008270']
trans_id=parts[0]
db=parts[3]
id=parts[4]

start=int(parts[6])
end=int(parts[7])
name="Name="+parts[5]
dbxref = "Dbxref=" + db + ':' + id
note="Note="+db
t=';'.join([name,dbxref,note])
print("!!!" + parts[11])

if len(parts) == 12:
    t = t + ";_Accession=" + parts[11]
if len(parts) == 14:
    go_terms = parts[13].split('|')
    t = t + ";Ontology_term=" + ','.join(go_terms)

print(t)
```

Why was not `if len(parts) == 12:` triggered and `_Accession` is missing in the final output as seen below?

```
!!!IPR001878
Name=;Dbxref=SMART:SM00343;Note=SMART;Ontology_term=GO:0003676,GO:0008270
```

Comment: `parts` looks like it has 14 elements to me.

Comment: `parts` has 14 elements, not 12. Please count yourself once. Or do `print(len(parts))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both questions have the same answer:

```py
len(parts)

Out[1]
14
```

So it will never enter the condition.

Answer (score 1):

`parts` as `14` elements, that's why it gives that output, however to know how many elements there are, do:

```
print(len(parts))
```

And it would output:

```
14
```